# Get daily sum of a numeric and plot the monthly average of this daily sum

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have two columns `myamount` which is a numeric column and a datetime column `mydate`.
For each day I want to get the sum of `myamount` (let's call it `daysum`) and then plot the monthly average of `daysum`. Thanks for the help!